I tried to make a image that is a hyper-link, but all it does is show up, but it doesn't go anywhere when i press it

 <a href="https://www.tus-wa.com/"></a>
    <img src="luckydip.png" alt="luckydip">
     </a>  

Whenever i load the page, the button doesn't work
i thought it would load The Ultimate Site. but instead it doesn't do anything, instead, it just loads the photo.

Because you have already closed the anchor tag.
Your code:
 <a href="https://www.tus-wa.com/"></a>
 <img src="luckydip.png" alt="luckydip">
 </a>  

Bug resolved:
 <a href="https://www.tus-wa.com/">
    <img src="luckydip.png" alt="luckydip">
 </a>  

